# How to destroy Hashtable in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have created a hashtable in a new module in Linux kernel using

```
static DEFINE_HASHTABLE(hash_ram, 14);
```

Then I have performed various functions on this hash table like iterating,insertion and deletion etc.

Now I am not able to comprehend in how to destroy this hash table

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't destroy it. You asked for it to be `static`, so it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot...so i need not explicitly destroy it..but has to free all the struct pointers which i have used?

Comment: You can initialize anything you need to on your `__init` and free it up on `__exit`. Test that you're not leaking memory by loading/unloading your module, generally `init_module()` and `cleanup_module()`. The footprint of that `static` property should be freed up, but anything inside of it is your responsibility, like iterating and deleting each node.